# Google Sheets: Change colour/highlight active spreadsheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors, tabs

Is there a way to automatically change the tab colour of the active sheet within Google Sheets, instead of just the sheet name changing to green?

Comment: "sheet name changing to green" ?

Comment: Currently, when working on the active sheet, the tab name colour will be green.

Comment: I have tried this, however 1. it doesn't seem to work for me and 2. i'm trying to avoid inserting the sheet name in the script

Comment: Try using an `onEdit` trigger and using `.getActiveSheet()` rather than inserting sheet name.

Comment: I'm sure that would work, However i'm very new to scripting in Google Sheets so this is changing the colour permanently, rather than only when the sheet is active. Would it be possible to provide the script?

Comment: Add your current script to the question via the edit button, then we can troubleshoot and make changes to what you have already built so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrote this based on the `.setTabColor()` script example supplied by google in the [Class Sheet Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setTabColor(String)).

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var active = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tabCol = active.getTabColor();

  if (tabCol == null) {
    //loop through all sheets and clear tab colour.
    for (var i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {
      sheets[i].setTabColor(null);
    }
    active.setTabColor("ff0000"); //change ff0000 to whatever colour hex value you'd like. 
  }
}
```

Basically this script will check if the sheet you're currently editing has a color assigned, if it does then it'll do nothing, if not then it'll give it a color. I've included a basic for loop to go through all of the sheets and clear their colors so that only the sheet you're currently editing will have a color assigned.

Comment: Cheers Ross! Is there any way to make this work when switching between tabs rather than requiring an edit being made?

Comment: Other than running the script at a ridiculous rate using a time trigger, I'm not sure how else you'd accomplish that.

Comment: Ah well, will make do with your solution. thanks for your help and perseverance!